# ElasticSearch: minimum_should_match and length of terms list

Tags: elasticsearch, intersection, pyelasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch I'm trying to use the `minimum_should_match` option on a `Terms Query` to find documents that have a list of `long`s that is `X%` similar to the list of `long`s I'm querying with.

e.g:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "fquery": {
            "query": {
                "terms": {
                    "mynum": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13],
                    "minimum_should_match": "90%",
                    "disable_coord": False
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will match two documents with a `mynum` list of:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
```

This works and is correct since the first document has a `10` at the end while the query contained a `13` and the second document contained an `11` where again the query contained a `13`.

Which means that 1 ou of 10 numbers in my query's list is different in the returned document and amounts to the allowed `90%` similarity (`minimum_should_match`) value in the query.

Now the issue that I have is that I would like the behaviour to be different in the sense that since the second document is longer and has 11 numbers in place of 10, the difference level should ideally have been higher since it has actually two values `11` and `12` that are not in the query's list. e.g:

Instead of computing the intersection of:

```
(list1) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]
```

with:

```
(list2) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
```

which is a `10%` difference

it should say that since `list2` is longer than `list1`, the intersection should be:

```
(list2) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
```

with:

```
(list1) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]
```

which is a `12%` difference

- Is this possible ?
- If not, how could I weight in the length of the list besides using a dense vector rather than a sparse one ? e.g:

using

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, , , , 13]
```

rather than:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]
```

Comment: a possible workaround is to set mapping of mynum to string type not_analyzed and enable   [norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#norms) i haven't tried it but probably worth a go